# Trouble Instantiating MKAnnotationPoint in my mapView while another UIContainerView is present

Tags: ios, mkannotation, uicontainerview

The basic scenario is under everything, I have a map view in my view controller.

Above that, I animate an "annotationCreateView" on top of it. This view is already instantiated and moves between isHidden = No to isHidden = Yes and animates on and off screen accordingly.

However, I'm having trouble adding an annotation to the user's current location at the end of animating the view onscreen.

For some reason, the view will animate all the way up, and then upon executing the code where I add the annotation view, the view will disappear.

If I check for the IsHidden, it says no, meaning that it should be present. However, if I try to reanimate it up, it will slide all the way up and disappear again.

This is my code:

```
createAnnotationViewPresent = true;
 [_annotationCreateView setHidden:NO];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height/2;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height;
    _annotationCreateView.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        point.coordinate = _mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
        [_mapView addAnnotation:point];
        self.point = point;
}];
```

Any suggestions appreciated, let me know if you need more code or information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Problem I was facing was that Apple's auto layout constraints make it such that after the View reaches the end of the animation and then the pin for the map view is placed on, it reaches a conflict. It then decides to resolve this conflict by resetting my view to it's original position and made it seem like it was never moved in the first place. At least as far as I understand :P. The solution to my problem was to simply relieve the view controller's auto layout constraints and voila, problem solved.